# Examining local variables up the stack in python

Tags: python, scope, callstack

I wrote a small function that looks up the stack one level and sees if there's a variable in it. but how do I turn this function into one that will look all the way up the stack until it finds a local variable buy some particular name?

```
import inspect
def variable_lookup(variable):
    parent_locals = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
    if variable in parent_locals.keys():
        return parent_locals[variable]
```

What I want is something that will loop until it looks through all the stack, trying to find the variable. How can I do this using inspect? Is there an easier way?

I started with this, but f_back doesn't return a frame object so I didn't know where to go from here:

```
import inspect
def variable_lookup(variable):
previous_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
while True:
    print(variable in previous_frame.f_locals.keys())
    previous_frame = inspect.getframeinfo(previous_frame)
```

So that code fails twith `AttributeError: 'Traceback' object has no attribute 'f_locals'`

Comment: `parent_locals.keys` is not a dictionary. That's a method reference. You don't need to call `keys()`, either, just use `if variable in parent_locals:`.

Comment: Really curious why you need this. Would seem to be subverting some design. There are probably better ways to do this.

Comment: @PeterWood: it can be helpful when debugging a weird problem, however.

Comment: @PeterWood I'm just working on an edge case where it would be really nice for a particular function to see the value of something without needing to have that value passed to it.

Comment: If the function is a member function, the object its on can carry the state instead of having it passed to the function.

Comment: @PeterWood that sounds like you're assuming OOP...

Comment: Well, you're certainly not doing functional programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a higher-level function available: [`inspect.stack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack). This gives you a list of `FrameInfo()` objects, which have a `frame` reference:

```
for frameinfo in inspect.stack(0):
    if variable in frameinfo.frame.f_locals:
        return frameinfo.frame.f_locals[variable]
```

I set the number of source code lines (the `context` parameter) to zero, no point in loading source code lines just to inspect local variables.

The `stack()` function is basically implemented as:

```
return inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe(), context)
```

and `getouterframes()` just follows the `frame.f_back` references until `None` is found. So you could also implement this with a `while` loop:

```
frame = inspect.currentframe()
while frame:
    if variable in frame.f_locals:
        return frame.f_locals[variable]
    frame = frame.f_back
```

This is certainly lighter weight, as this avoids creating `FrameInfo()` instances for all frames in the stack, avoids introspection of filenames for all frames, and doesn't need to access all the linked frames if the variable is found early.

Comment: In the code blocks above; it should be inspect.currentframe() rather than inspect.*get*currentframe().

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe