# How can I override global variables just for the scope of callees of a function in Python?

Tags: python, scope, global

I'm writing a decorator which needs to pass data to other utility functions; something like:

```
STORE = []
def utility(message):
  STORE.append(message)

def decorator(func):
  def decorator_wrap(*args, **kwargs):
    global STORE
    saved_STORE = STORE
    STORE = list()
    func(*args, **kwargs)
    for line in STORE:
      print(line)
    STORE = saved_STORE
  return decorator_wrap

@decorator
def foo(x):
  # ...
  utility(x)
  # ...
```

But that's kind of yuck, and not thread safe.  Is there a way to override `utility()`'s view of `STORE` for the duration of `decorator_wrap()`?  Or some other way to signal to `utility()` that there's an alternate `STORE` it should use?

Alternatively, to present an different `utility()` to `foo()` and all its callees; but that seems like exactly the same problem.

Comment: Does `decorator_wrap()` have to use STORE? Why dont just use another variable imstead?

Comment: @Jon_Kle it doesn't have to use STORE, it just has to be able to communicate with `utility`.  Whatever global I use risks conflicting with other threads.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58598665/2417578) I find that I can implement it this way:

```
import inspect

STORE = []

def utility(message):
  global STORE
  store = STORE
  frame = inspect.currentframe()
  while frame:
    if 'LOCAL_STORE' in frame.f_locals:
      store = frame.f_locals['LOCAL_STORE']
      break;
    frame = frame.f_back

  store.append(message)

def decorator(func):
  def decorator_wrap(*args, **kwargs):
    LOCAL_STORE = []
    func(*args, **kwargs)
    for line in LOCAL_STORE:
      print(line)
  return decorator_wrap
```

Buuuut while reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) I see `f_globals` is present in every stack frame.  I think the more efficient method would be to inject my local into  my callee's `f_globals`.  This would be similar to setting an environment variable before executing another command, but I don't know if it's legal.

Comment: See [context variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html)