# Are Python functions' global view inherited from callers, and can I inject things that aren't actually global?

Tags: python, scope

While trying to figure out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73747778/2417578) I see from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) that every stack frame has an `f_globals` member.

Is that designed to be manipulated on a per-callee basis?

I want to advertise a local variable to callees of a function, in a sort of "while we're within this call tree, this is the context decorators and utilities will use" way, without having to modify every function in the potential call graph to pass this along.  It's not a great decorator when you have to rewrite the decorated function, after all.

Comment: No, Python does not have dynamic scope, it has static scope. The globals of a function are set *where the function is defined*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then why does the `f_globals` member exist, and how does it change?

Comment: Stack frames are not designed to be manipulated, period.  That information is made visible solely for the purpose of debugging.

Comment: Not sure why the implementation works that way, presumably, it is set to the same thing as `the_function.__globals__`, but note, both of these attribute are read-only. Of course, the a globals/module namespace can be mutated (it is, after all, just a regular dict). Dynamically mutating it sounds like... a bad design decision, but you are free to mutate it

Comment: The call frame doesn't exist until the function is actually called. (And every call to a function creates a new call frame.)

Comment: Also, probably important to mention, in Python, the "global" scope is not really global, it is actually the *module* scope.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: that's correct, but I think what's more relevant here is that the function's global scope --that is, it's __global__ attribute, is a simple dictionary, not a hierarchy of scopes. So you can't inject a new level into the scope hierarchy. That's pretty explicitly not provided for by the Python data model. If a function has no required arguments and no nonlocal references, you can evaluate it with  a different globals dictionary using `eval(func.__code__, myGlobals)`, but `myGlobals` has to contain all referenced globals; there's no fallback mechanism.

Comment: "why does the f_globals member exist, and how does it change?" because globals only have module-wide scope instead of truly global scope; and also to accomodate compiling functions dynamically with `exec`. You will notice that you cannot actually change which object is used, but only modify keys/values - which is equivalent to just modifying the corresponding global variables.

Comment: Note, too, that `f_globals` is simply taken from the function being executed. The function itself maintains a reference to its global scope; this is simply copied into the frame for convenience, rather than having the frame store a reference to the function itself and accessing the globals indirectly through the function.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I think I've learned so far:

The call stack can contain different values of `r_globals` for each frame because each function has "global" state that is shared within the module in which it is defined and not the whole execution state.  Since calls can cross between modules, `r_globals` can be different in every frame.

Even if you create a new module and copy a function into it, `__globals__` is a read-only member of that function object, so when you call it its globals revert back to the original module where it was first defined, not the modified globals of its adopted parent.

Similarly, if you use `exec()` with modified globals, or if you can build your own copy of the callee code with modified `__globals__` you'll only get one layer deep before a subsequent call reverts back to that function's original view of its globals.

---

It looks like the intended solution to this problem is [context variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html), which addresses some problems that thread-local storage fails to handle.